# Wait for async call on run before config is executed (Angular JS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to resolve a http call before any of states are loaded

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .run(function($http, MyFactory) {
        $http.get('/api..')
           .success(function(data){
                MyFactory.setData(data);
                //Store data in a service
            });
    })
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
        .state('main', {...})
        .state('main.app'{
            url: '/app'
            resolve: {
               data: function(MyFactory) {
                  MyFactory.getData();
                // This block needs to be run after my $http call in 'run' has been resolved.
                return ..
               } 
            }
         }
     });
```

---

```
.factory('MyFactory', function () {
     var data = '';
     return {
        setData: function(_data) {
           data = _data
        },
        getData: function() {
           return data;
        }
     } 
};
```

I tried to put the `$http` as a resolve in my first state `.main` but if yo go to `.main.app` directly, the first resolve is executed after the second one.

Comment: I'd suggest don't do this call from the `.run` function, do that `ajax` from the factory it self & the method which will do that ajax will return a promise.. So that method would get call from the `resolve` of `state` & return that `promise` from resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can craft dependency promise resolution with the following pattern, where `setData` chain will complete in `.main` and will be satisfied when we resolve `getData` in `.main.app`. No need to do this in `.run()`,  instead, below is a simple interpretation of what I believe you are trying to accomplish...

```
.factory('MyFactory', function($http, $q) {

    function setData() {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('/endpoint').success(function(response) {

            // do something with data - we just want to resolve the response so this block is executed

            deferred.resolve(response)
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    function getData() {
        return $http.get('/endpoint');
    }

    return {
        getData: 'getData',
        storeData: 'storeData'
    }
});
```

---

```
.state('main', {
    resolve : {
        set: ['MyFactory', function(MyFactory) {
            return MyFactory.setData();
        }]
    }
})
.state('main.app', {
    resolve: {
        data: ['set', 'MyFactory', function(saved, MyFactory) {
            // -- set must be resolved
            return MyFactory.getData();
        }]
    }
});
```

Comment: First a $http.get(.. followed by a $http.post? Why should I post? What url am I suppose to have in the post?

Comment: Ah, sorry. "Set" would probably be a better name. I just store it locally in my factory. I removed the post. Can't get it to work.

Comment: Idk - I guess `storeDate` sounded like a post to me (or `storeData?`) typo? Are you doing something with data or a date?

Comment: Ahh I see, hmm, let me think about it for a min

Comment: I tried editing a bit to meed your needs more, I _think_ I see what you're trying to do here. Could you let me know if this works?